# 2003 Toyota Rav4 ECT Too Low for Readiness Monitor Drive Pattern

Tags: toyota, coolant, emissions, rav4

I recently failed an emissions test because my CAT and EVAP readiness monitors were "Not Ready" following a reset check engine light a few weeks back, which told me that the engine coolant wasn't running hot enough. I've confirmed this with a ODB-II scan tool.

According to pg 13 of this [document](http://www.toyotapart.com/READINESS_MONITOR_DRIVE_PATTERNS_T-EG02-003.pdf) (which is for a 2002, but I assume they are similar), my engine coolant temperature needs to be 176 degrees F for the CAT monitor to start running.  My scanner is telling me that my ECT is running at ~160 degrees F.

I can't figure out if this means a sensor is busted, or something else (like cold weather) is causing the ECT to be that low. Can anyone recommend a next step that I might try on my own instead of taking it into the shop?

Comment: How cold is the weather where you are? That might be important information

Comment: Lately it's been in the 30s and 40s.

Comment: Duncan, nice job writing this question and providing prior research.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terms of possible **root causes** for failure, the following scenarios are likely culprits for a cooling system to run too cool:

- A temperature sensor that's reporting lower-than-actual temperatures due to issues like drift/fouling/calibration.
- A sticking thermostat that is flowing more coolant than necessary to maintain 176 °F.
- Really cold ambient air temperature which prevents the system from settling down at the desired 176 °F.

---

The **most likely culprit** based on the information provided is a sticking thermostat:

- If the temperature sensor malfunctions, one would observe negative temperatures with the scan tool, which in this case isn't happening. While temperature misrepresentation is a possibility, most temperature sensors have a tendency to either work well or not work at all.
- A stuck-open thermostat will give slightly-below-par engine coolant temperatures, as is the case here.
- More information is needed about the ambient air temperature in order to comment on it.

Comment: I would concur with the sticking thermostat. I doubt ambient air temperature would have much of anything to do with it. As long as the thermostat is functioning correctly, there shouldn't be an *under temperature* condition. A gasoline engine produces way more heat than it uses. Once up to temperature it will maintain it without issue. A completely closed thermostat will allow that to happen fairly quickly.

Comment: Just had to mention that I thought this was a really **COMPLETE** answer. +1

Comment: Turned out to be the thermostat.  Quick fix, thanks for the detailed response.